# Very large hole around main drain line. How to fill?

Tags: insulation, pipe, sealing

There is a very large hole around the main drain line in my house.  I can see it through the fireplace (another problem to tackle) and can also partially access from the basement ceiling.  I'm wondering what is the best way to seal around it? Ideally it would help insulate because cold comes up from the basement.  It looks way too big to use something like spray foam. (I'm sorry I don't know how to post the actual picture here.)

[image]
!(https://photos.app.goo.gl/bAq3tiK4upS4XNHv8)

Comment: Is that knob and tube wiring in the picture still in use?

Comment: why can we see two rooms below this?   The hole is quite common in houses, two rooms not having a ceiling is less common.

Answer (score 2):

**Where's the floor?**. On the upper floor, replace the missing floor around the drain.  Cut the new boards so they fit tightly around the drain.  Fill the small gap between the new boards and the drain with spray foam or caulk.

That should significantly reduce the flow of cold/hot air between this room and the basement, and entirely eliminate the problems such as you can see the basement.

If you want to take it further, let's see a picture of your basement ceiling.  If it is generally insulated from the house you can add insulation in this spot.  But you don't always want to do that.   If there is generally a finished ceiling you might want to repair that in this spot just as you repaired the floor.

**Additional thoughts on your comment and pictures**

You have some old Knob & Tube wiring.  Now that you have floors and ceilings open is a good time to eliminate as much of it as possible. That you also have newer NM cable is a promising sign, perhaps the K&T is no longer in use.  It's a good idea to remove it because it can freak out inspectors, insurance companies and future buyers of the property even if it's disconnected and not in use.

You have a joist, a wall, a beam (supporting the joist) and some ledger boards to work with for supporting the floor repair.  My suggestion is to replace those little bits of ledger board with a larger, continuous one ... basically a joist against the wall and use the beam for support, not just the screws or nails into the wall.    Then you can add some additional framing around the pipe, supported by the joists and supporting the floor repair.

I note this is a subfloor, so maybe you'll be adding flooring on top of it, in which case the gaps don't all have to be filled perfectly.

[image]

You

Comment: Thanks for your reply! How should I go about installing boards around the pipe? There are no joists or anything for me to nail it into.  Could I cut it oversized by a bit and nail it over the hole maybe?  Here are pics from the basement looking up.  This is an old home and not insulated yet.  (https://photos.app.goo.gl/rM1yMXLnpuVdYbv78)  (https://photos.app.goo.gl/62MyTnxrDehj6p449)

Comment: I added suggestions  to the answer.

Comment: Thanks again! That's extremely helpful.  There won't be any flooring installed on top.  This is actually inside my fireplace so it will be hidden from view.  Just needed something functional, doesn't have to look good.                                                                                         Unfortunately some of the old knob and tube is still in use though a lot has been updated.  I'm saving up to have it all rewired eventually.  I know how scary it is!

Comment: I don't understand what you mean by "Inside my fireplace".  Obviously you don't have a wooden floor inside your firebox but assuming you mean something sensible, if it will be hidden from view and absolutely 100% definitely nobody will ever stand on or place anything on it, then sure, don't do any of what I said ... add a layer of flooring on top, resting on the existing floor and hugging the pipe, or you could even use hard foam insulation to close the hole.  But it can't be "I don't intend to stand on it" .. it has to be "it's not possible for anyone, ever, to do so".

Comment: No, it's impossible to stand on.  It's inside the walls.  The original firebox has crumbled apart. It was super old and made of something resembling drywall but I don't know what exactly it was.  That's another problem I need to solve - how to deal with the huge hold which used to house the firebox.  The pipe and flooring in the pictures sit just to the right of the firebox so they wouldn't catch fire.